# Return result of Find as IMongoQueryable in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I created the method which returns ***IMongoQueryable*** as result and the method is following:

```
GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey).Find(query).As<T>();
```

The problem is this returns as ***IFindFluent***. Before there were extension method ***AsQueryable*** which solved this, but now there is no that method anymore. I tried using `IMongoCollectionExtensions.AsQueryable<T>` and it works only with ***GetCollection*** but when I add this part for ***Find*** and ***As*** there were several errors. Any tip how to solve this?

Comment: `ToList` or any other linq method

Comment: @dododo I tried that, but it didn't help as then it is List and not IMongoQueryable

Comment: `Find` is not designed to be IQuerable. IQuerable expects using `Aggregate`

Comment: However, maybe you don't really mean real `IQueryable`. IFindFluent works in really similar way. You can append different methods to IFindFluent instance which effectively makes the same logic as IQueryable and only when you call a LINQ method like `ToList`, the combined find query will be send to a server

Comment: Ohhhhh maybe you are right, as I had here to  update the method from 2.0 to 2.17 version and in 2.0 it returned as IQueryable. I saw that doesn't exist anymore so I tried to put it as IMongoQueryable with IMongoCollectionExtensions.AsQueryable<T> 
But if it is makes the same logic, I ll just change the output type and had to make more changes were that method is called